# Redirect url to new url in java code

Tags: java

I am working on an application, and it connects with url and retrieve data from page. Unfortunately its not reaching the page which I am interested in.

How to redirect it to desired page through GET method in java code?

Output "readline" method shows me its hitting /MRcgi/MRlogin.pl, but I wish to go to different url

O/p

```
 <TITLE> Service Core</TITLE>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var replace_function = function() {
                    window.location.replace('/MRcgi/MRlogin.pl?USER=***p&PASSWORD=webauth&PROJECTID=-1');
                }
```

Code-

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    String userPassword = "*****";

    String encoding = new String(
            org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
                    .encodeBase64(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils
                            .getBytesUtf8(userPassword)));



    ((HttpURLConnection) con).setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);


    // Send post request
    ///
    // con.setDoOutput(false); 
      /*  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream()); 
        System.out.println("1111" +wr); 
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters); 
        wr.flush(); 
        wr.close();*/


    int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) con).getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + con);
    //System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    //window.location.replace("");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
    //con.

    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println("-----" + in.readLine());
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        //response.append(inputLine);

    }
    in.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Raz, `URL` methods don't follow redirects and not so agile with specifying some additional HTTP behaviors: request type, headers, etc.

I'd recommend to use [Apache HTTP Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html) instead for your needs. Here is [an example with authentication from official docs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/examples.html):

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
        new AuthScope("httpbin.org", 80),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "passwd"));
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
        .build();
try {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd");

    System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    try {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
```

Note that you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to implicitly close resources if you use JDK7 or higher.

Comment: No its not working for me. I am not able to run "httpclient.execute(httpget);" . I am receiving an error - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://help.com:443: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
Jun 21, 2017 11:33:07 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute